# How the jobno generated in DBMS_JOB.submit scheduler

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

i have the job in my PLSQL package & its returning jobno when i debug , how this job number generated ?

```
 DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(jobNo, 'begin AsyncContractInvDet_pkg. async_response(JOB); end;');
log_debug('jobNo::::'||jobNo);
```

How to write equivalent DBMS_scheduler.create  for above  job and  where i can pass jobno as in parameter because my pkg.proc having in parameter

Comment: Is the need for the procedure you are calling with the job to know what job it's being run by?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter *how* the number is generated by `DBMS_JOB`? The only thing that matters is that it is unique.

`DBMS_SCHEDULER` doesn't use job numbers at all: it identifies jobs by name *that you provide* and does not generate the identifier for you. See the [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/support-for-DBMS_JOB.html#GUID-16FC3667-B573-411D-923E-5D435A604FA3) for equivalent examples. Scheduled jobs are treated just like other database objects, and in most cases should not be *created* dynamically. Each job should be defined statically as part of your schema DDL, and only *executed* dynamically.

You will need to modify your DDL to create named jobs once, just like any other package or stored procedure, then modify your code to use `DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB` to execute jobs by name.